# Binding Grid column width

Tags: .net, wpf, wpf-controls, binding

I am facing the following problem in the design of my XAML.

I need to arrive at the end to arrange my data like a grid but with a custom `DataTemplate`.
So I create a top `Grid` which contains the two header lables of the data items. 
Below the `Grid` I build a `StackPanel` with an `ItemsControl` which includes the `DataTemplate` which displays my data. Everything is ok, when I run the application I get the header lables and the data items below like a grid. My problem is that the labels and the content of the items are not aligned correctly. So I thought about binding the `Width` of the header lable columns to the `ActualWidth` of the `ItemTemplate`, but unfortunately that does not work.

Is there any clean way to achive this?
Thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a easy way to do this using `SharedSizeGroup` in the grid columns and assinging `Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True"` for the parent.

e.g.

```
    <StackPanel Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
        <Grid Name="Headers">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="A"/>
                <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="B"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="Name"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="Occupation"/>
        </Grid>
        <ItemsControl Name="Items" ItemsSource="{Binding Data}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="A"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="B"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Occupation}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </StackPanel>
```

All the items will have the same widths in the columns, the only thing that you might need to line up manually is the headers section above the items, depending on margin settings and the like.

Comment: +1 - this is one of those non-obvious WPF techniques that everyone should know about.

Comment: @Robert Rossney: Absolutely, and it's a rather elegant solution to a common problem.